# Is there a performance penalty in accessing the Windows API through Delphi?

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi

I've had experience programming with ye old Win32 API in C++ several years ago, and recently I've been involved in development with Delphi. I immediately recognised a lot of the functions from the Windows API (e.g., `CreateThread`, `CreateWindowEx`, etc, etc).

I have found Embarcadero's documentation incomplete (to say the least), and typically refer to the Microsoft website for documentation. Where, might I add, all the functions are defined in C, which makes it difficult for the non-C folk out there (but easier for me).

What I want to know is - given that the Delphi function signatures are identical to the C function signatures provided by Microsoft - does a call to the Delphi Windows API function **immediately** call the Windows API function, or does it call an identical Delphi function which **then** calls the Windows API function and returns the result, the former meaning no distinguishable difference in performance compared to the corresponding C code, while the later meaning something of a performance penalty?

Comment: You can Ctrl+click on a function in Delphi to see where it leads to. E.g. most of the WinAPI functions are directly calling these functions from system DLLs

Comment: Really? You're worrying about performance in GUI calls?

Comment: No, I'm not worrying about this, especially seeing as it is a direct call into the Windows-provided DLLs. What I was doing was asking whether or not a performance penalty existed, part of wanting to know being to better understand how Delphi works "under the hood".

Comment: +1 for stirring up a hornet's nest.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Read the source. A call to `CreateWindowEx` is defined in the `Windows.pas` unit as a direct call to the `CreateWindowExW` function in `User32.DLL` (from XE5's source - similar definitions are found in all versions of Delphi for the supported OS versions):

```
function CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle: DWORD; lpClassName: LPCWSTR;
  lpWindowName: LPCWSTR; dwStyle: DWORD; X, Y, nWidth, nHeight: Integer;
  hWndParent: HWND; hMenu: HMENU; hInstance: HINST; lpParam: Pointer): HWND;
  stdcall; external user32 name 'CreateWindowExW';
```

So the answer to your specific question is no. There is no performance penalty. A call to a WinAPI function in Delphi does not incur a performance hit.

Comment: You're right. It looks like the signature is just to provide symbol resolution into the DLL: `function CreateThread; external kernel32 name 'CreateThread';` Good to know.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This answer is correct. Delphi design is as efficient as it could be for a native application under Windows.

Comment: @arnaud No it is not. Read the answer again. It claims that a call to a function declared with external is a "direct" call. It manifestly is not. Do you believe that call+jmp is direct?

Comment: As efficient as it can be is one thing (which is arguable - see comments to David's answer), making a direct call or not is another. When we call CreateWindowEx, we make a direct call to the stub in 'windows.pas', not to the function in user32. That's not something to argue about.

Comment: I'm not saying that this answer is factually wrong, as it does not actually claim user code directly calls api. But the conclusion it draws in the last paragraph does not quite rely on what is said in the first paragraph.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I take issue with this sentence *A call to CreateWindowEx is defined in the Windows.pas unit as a direct call to the CreateWindowExW function in User32.DLL.* That is not correct, at least the way I understand it.

Comment: @David - I see your point, what you object is probably how it's meant to mean. However, probably, technically we can say that the call in the windows.pas is direct (but we have to call that direct call first, which is missing in this answer).

Comment: @David: You're splitting hairs again. I said it is *defined as a direct call*, meaning that it **does not first call a Delphi wrapper function before calling the API**, which is specifically what the question asked. That's precisely what I stated, precisely what the code I pasted in shows, and once again you're putting words in my mouth (or at least my keystrokes) that I did not say. Please read the **actual words I've written** instead of making some wildly inaccurate interpretation of them and claiming my answer is "incorrect".

Comment: You said, "A call to CreateWindowEx is defined in the Windows.pas unit as a direct call to the CreateWindowExW function in User32.DLL". I take that to mean that calling `CreateWindowEx` calls into user32 directly.

Comment: You also wrote, "Read the source.". Well that does not help. What counts is how the compiler generates the code. How it builds the IAT. And so on.

Comment: Reading the source clearly shows that it's a mere mapping (as directly as possible) to the underlying API. There's no 30-line Delphi code block that provides some sort of "wrapper" function (which is *again* exactly what I said the source shows). Once again, words taken out of context to mean somewhere other than what I actually wrote.

Comment: @KenWhite CALL + JMP trampoline is not the only solution. For instance, MSVC manages without. It just does direct CALL.

Comment: "You're asserting that I said that somehow the WinAPI code is directly loaded into Delphi's memory so it can be called". No I am not. And that doesn't even really make any sense. Delphi is a language/IDE, it doesn't have memory. I'm not sure what you mean. A DLL is mapped into a process address space. A call into the DLL is a CALL or JMP that transfers execution into the code of the DLL.

Comment: And no, reading the source really does not help to understand how the emitted code is implemented. Indeed there's no large Delphi code block that acts as a wrapper. But examining the code does not prove that. Only examining the emitted code can prove that. When you examine the omitted code you will find that Delphi uses a trampoline. When you look at the code that MSVC, for instance, produces, you'll find it manages without a trampoline. If you would study the emitted code you would reach the same conclusion.

Comment: David: OK. Please provide benchmarks showing the noticeable performance hit that Delphi's mechanism imposes over that used by MSVC, so that we can measure that "significant difference" that Delphi's huge overhead imposes. When you do so, I'll change my answer to read that Delphi indeed imposes a penalty. (Make sure you post both the MSVC and Delphi source for those benchmarks along with the results, if you would be so kind.) That *is* what the question asked, after all, and what my answer addressed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan MSVC generates an *indirect call* which won't be faster than a JMP trampoline. The calling convention used will have probably more impact (depending on the function signature) that what you are arguing. +1 for this answer which focuses on the question, and state that there is no performance penalty.

Comment: @Ken I don't claim that. Where do I say that? I just said that Delphi calls into external functions are indirect. Which is what the asked about?

Comment: @David: You said my answer is incorrect, and my answer was "There is no performance penalty. A call to a WinAPI function in Delphi does not incur a performance hit.". Therefore, you're saying there is a performance hit, and I'm asking you to provide evidence that my answer is incorrect as you've stated. If you're not saying that, your statement that my answer is incorrect is wrong and the comment should be removed.

Comment: **Q** *Does a call to the Delphi Windows API function immediately call the Windows API function?* **A** *A call to CreateWindowEx is defined in the Windows.pas unit as a direct call to the CreateWindowExW function in User32.DLL.* Do you stand by that statement? I agree that any perf implications are invariably negligible. I have never said otherwise.

Comment: @David: That's not the answer to the question. The question asked was "Is there a performance hit?", and my answer to that was "There is no performance hit." The **relevant part of my answer is correct**, and therefore your statement that it isn't is in fact wrong unless you prove there is in fact a performance hit. If you want to get pissy about nitpicking my answers, nitpick the actual answers I give instead of something else. I stand by my statement that there is no performance penalty for calling a WinAPI function in Delphi, which was the question asked here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The question was about performance, and if it does "call an identical Delphi function which then calls the Windows API". Ken's answered this: there is no such wrapping function in Delphi. This is a direct call - no need of going down to the asm here, which is just pointless when dealing with `CreateThread, CreateWindowEx` (which were the API in the question). Even for the fastest APIs - like `GetCurrentThreadID()` or `MulDiv()` which do not switch to kernel mode - a JMP trampoline or an indirect call is the same. This is a direct call, with no wrapping function.

Comment: @KenWhite Your answer is factually incorrect. It is easy to fix it. You can say that: "The compiler emits a CALL to a thunk with then performs a JMP into the DLL. Whilst not a direct call, this is to all intents indistinguishable and almost certainly has no measurable performance implications."

Comment: @David: There is nothing to fix. It is factually correct, until you provide benchmarks as I've requested. My answer is that there is no performance penalty.

Comment: No benchmark is needed to demonstrate that the call is not direct. Why would a benchmark help?

Comment: @David: You're being intentionally obtuse. My answer to the question "Is there a performance penalty" is "No, there is no performance penalty". That is the factual portion of my answer, and I'm tired of listening to your nattering. If you disagree with my answer, feel free to downvote it. The call is direct in the regard that there is no Delphi implementation of a wrapper function (there is no function declaration in the Windows unit implementation that has a `function..begin <statements> end;` block which then calls the CreateWindowEx function).

Comment: So you agree with me that the call is in fact indirect?

Comment: @David: No. I'm saying I'm tired of your irrelevant pedantry. The poster asked if there was a performance penalty, which I answered. In a comment to the original question (by the question poster), it was clarified: "What I was doing was asking whether or not a performance penalty existed", which again is the question I answered. The distinction you've locked your obsessive pendantry on is meaningless with regard to the question asked and the answer I provided to that question. Again, if it bothers you so much, feel free to downvote my correct answer to the question asked.

Comment: So you believe that the call is direct? You don't believe that the call is to a trampoline? Wouldn't it be easier to correct your answer? Don't you prefer to get the facts right?

Comment: @David: What would be easier would be for you to just stop being so annoying. I've proven (with evidence) that I've correctly answered the question that was asked here, and your quibbling over "tomato" or "tomahto" is irrelevant, as is your obsessive need to get someone to agree that you're right. I'm not wasting time arguing with you any longer. If you want to keep commenting here, feel free to do so. As I've said at least twice before, if you want to downvote my correct answer to the question asked, please do so. If my answer is wrong, post the benchmarks that prove it as I've asked.

Comment: Benchmarks? I explained why they don't help. The sentence I highlighted in your answer is clearly wrong. You clearly believe, and state, that the call is direct. That is manifestly wrong. Correct it or not. Your choice. As for perf, it doesn't matter one way or the other. As everyone agrees. The only bone of contention is whether or not the call is direct. You say it is. I say it is not.

Comment: @David: Actually, you're wrong, based on your own answer: "Then, Windows.CloseHandle is implemented like this: `JMP kernel32.CloseHandle`." My answer: "CreateWindowEx` in the Windows.pas .. direct call to the `CreateWindowExW` function in User32.DLL". By your own answer, my statement is correct. Yours says a JMP from Windows.pas to `kernel32`, mine says a call from Windows.pas to `user32`. They're saying the same thing.

Comment: No. They are not saying the same thing. It's easy for you to clarify it. I've responded to comments to my answer to improve it.

Comment: @David: What I see in the comments you reference is the same pedantic insistence on the same topic as you've posted in these comments, and multiple people telling you the same thing I am. In fact, [Arnaud](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087802/is-there-a-performance-penalty-in-accessing-the-windows-api-through-delphi/22087940?noredirect=1#comment33525258_22088863) even pointed out you're obsessing over nothing because the question asked here was about **the performance impact**. You've gotten your arrogant pedantry latched onto something that **isn't even the question**.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you and Ken have wasted 3 dozen comments **nitpicking** implementation details that are **irrelevant** to the question asked or the answer provided.  The fact remains, Delphi **static links** to most API functions (some APIs use delay loading, and some use wrappers to account for OS version differences), so WHO CARES whether calling an API function statically is a **direct** call or an **IAT jump** call. Call a static API function and it ends up calling into a system DLL either way. Please put this discussion to rest already and move on.

Comment: It's in the question. It doesn't matter for perf. It's interesting to know how it's implemented. Information that won't be found in the source.

Comment: @Remy I'd call it load time or explicit dynamic linking. I don't see any need to continue discussing any of this. I think the details are clear now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Exactly my point! Delphi rocks on calling external unmanaged libraries or APIs, like any serious native solutions.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez I think the question is more than, "does Delphi rock?"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Delphi rocks so much that its Oracle is stoned... http://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/ancient-cultures/daily-life-and-practice/the-oracle-of-delphi%E2%80%94was-she-really-stoned/

Answer (score 8):

> Does a call to the Delphi Windows API function immediately call the Windows API function?

Not it does not.

For sake of argument let us consider a call to `CloseHandle`. This is declared in the `Windows` unit and implemented using `external`. When you call it, you do in fact call a function named `CloseHandle` in the `Windows` unit. So in pseudo assembler it looks like this:

```
.... prepare parameters
CALL     Windows.CloseHandle
```

Then, `Windows.CloseHandle` is implemented like this:

```
JMP      kernel32.CloseHandle
```

So, compared to a direct call, there is a call to a thunk function, and then a jump into the Win32 DLL. This is known as a trampoline.

It could be implemented differently. The compiler could emit code to call directly into the Win32 DLL. And some compilers will do this. For instance, the equivalent asm for this call as emitted by MSVC would be:

```
CALL     DWORD PTR [__imp__CloseHandle@4]
```

Here, `__imp__CloseHandle@4` is the address of a location in memory which contains the address of `CloseHandle` in the Windows DLL. The loader writes the actual address of `CloseHandle` into `__imp__CloseHandle@4` at load time.

Which is more efficient? Impossible to say for sure without profiling. But I'm confident that any difference will be significant in a vanishingly small number of cases.

Of course it is possible also for code to be generated that would call directly with no indirection. That would involve the loader patch every call to the function. That is probably a bad idea however because it would lead to a large number of load time fixups which would be a performance issue at startup. That said, it would be pretty much the same as a DLL that needs to be relocated at load time. In any case, I know of no tool chain that adopts this policy.

Perhaps what you are concerned about is whether these functions are the real Win32 functions. Or whether there is a layer around them that changes the meaning. These are the real Win32 functions. There is no Delphi documentation because these are Win32 functions. The Win32 documentation on MSDN is the authoritative source of documentation.

As many people have said, the Win32 functions are called with no intervening layer. So they are directly called in these sense that your parameters are passed un-modified to the API functions. But the calling mechanism is indirect in the sense that it uses a trampoline. Semantically there is no difference.

Comment: This is an implementation detail of how [library linking does occur](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681914). This is how Windows load its .dll: at loading, it resolves the symbol names and fill a JMP table. Then individual calls in the code refers to this JMP table. This allows to map only the JMP table part of the .dll in memory, without the need to map the whole .dll code, which remains untouched. As such, the **Delphi design is as efficient as it could be for a native application**.

Comment: @arnaud Nope. It could be more efficient, as is done in other compilers. The call could be directly into the windows dll.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If you did that (made a relocation item at every call), there's a good chance that the entire code portion of the executable would have to be loaded into memory already at startup, thus vastly increasing the load time *and* the memory consumption (since the loader can only patch a relocation item once the memory is allocated and loaded from the disk image). By implementing is as a JMP table, only the JMP table *needs* to be loaded into memory by the loader, so that it can patch the relocations (and of course the entry point code).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: (continued) ...so yes, the actual *call* to the Windows API would be (slightly) more efficient, but at the cost of a much longer load time, and a much higher memory consumption. So which is most "efficient"?

Comment: @David I already answered those questions in my previous comment. However, your assertion that "it could me more efficient" is open to interpretation, as "efficient" could be more than just the simple call to the API. And in my opinion, Arnaud is correct in stating that the Delphi way is the most efficient way of doing it (it also decreases the size of the relocation table to one per API function called, and not one per call), and thus (IMO) your statement "It could be more efficient" is incorrect.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't have to - it's self-evident (in the sense that "efficient" doesn't only apply to the time used for the actual call). By having a JMP table, the loader can load a file containing 2.000.000 calls to a Windows API and only need to patch one single entry in the file. By calling the API directly at each and every invocation of the API function, the loader will have to patch 2.000.000 places in the file, which even you will acknowledge takes longer time than patching a single entry.

Comment: But if you can make an executable file with 2.000.000 individual calls to the same API function that comes out smaller (ie. more efficient) and loads faster (ie. more efficiently), then I am all ears. However, it will probably not be possible to verify this last thing, as there are many other things that will play a role, but common sense tells me that if the loader needs to patch 2.000.000 places in the code it'll take longer than to patch 1 place. Don't you agree?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Once again: That question has already been answered. Please re-read comment #4 (the second one from me). Also: Your claim that the direct call is more "efficient" is ambigious. It is *faster* (at the time of the call), but it is less *efficient* (memory-wise and load-time-wise).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are making assumptions which did make sense with a 8086, but do not make much sense with modern CPUs. Depending on the CPU inner cache content, it could be of NO cost to have a JMP instruction in a JMP wrapper table which is already cached *at micro-op* level. Writing a whole answer about such granularity is pointless, with today's CPU architecture. What may cost are each transition in the OS kernel, or access to non-cached memory location. This JMP indirection used by Delphi is a well established fast and safe way, which helps loading executables faster.

Comment: @HeartWare This was the whole point of my first comment. David « pèse des oeufs de mouche dans une balance en toile d'araignée » [(flies’ eggs are weighed on spiders’ web)](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Carlet_de_Chamblain_de_Marivaux#cite_note-31).

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Why do you think MSVC do it the other way then? And as for "writing a whole answer about such granularity is pointless", well, I try to answer the question that was asked. Which was, "Does a call to the Delphi Windows API function immediately call the Windows API function?" Do you still believe that the answer to that is yes?

Comment: As someone who works with embedded systems where the load maybe will happen once a month, and where "modern CPUs" can well be 586-based (i.e. the Quark), I'm highly inclined to agree with David here.  The definition of "efficient" is dependent on context, and if I am concerned foremost about execution speed, then making a CALL instead of a JMP+CALL right now is far more important to me than how long it took to load the app last week.  The OP question specifically asked about call performance.  David addressed that question.

Comment: @HeartWare Actually you don't need to patch every single call. I suggest you study how it is done by other compilers. Read this: http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/10/how-dll-imports-work/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan A CALL + JMP or an indirect CALL is almost of the same speed, or - depending on the CPU architecture and cache context - could be slower for an indirect CALL, which mixes code and data caches. In this articlle, the argue that "It doesn’t require an extra level of jumping (such as a trampoline would), which keeps the performance reasonable" - is IMHO just not true. **A modern out-of-order CPU do not execute the asm opcodes directly: the disassembly is by now way the execution plan!** What matters is true timing, and here any kernel switch matters, whereas a trampoline JMP don't.

Comment: @ctacke Are you sure that "making a CALL instead of a JMP+CALL right now is far more important to me"? This was true for a 8086, but not for today's CPU: an indirect CALL may be slower than CALL+JMP. Several opcodes may be faster than one, depending on the CPU out-of-order implementation, and execution context. If the trampoline is already in the [Micro-operation cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-operation_cache), the [pipelined planner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline) may execute it in one cycle, since there is no branching. See http://www.agner.org/optimize

Comment: @Arnaud I won't disagree with those perf comments. I just think that the answer to the question is that the call is indirect. I should make my answer say nothing about perf.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The question was about performance. I just [checked the micro-op tables for Haswell](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) (page 192). *A) Indirect CALL* = 3 μops fused domain or 4 μops unfused domain. *B) CALL + JMP* = 2+1 μops fused domain or 2+1 μops unfused domain. And this does not take into consideration pipelining optimization, which may be broken by the memory access of the indirect call.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Your interpretation was that. I read this line: "Does a call to the Delphi Windows API function immediately call the Windows API function?" How would you answer that particular question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Please read the whole sentence. You answered just the first part of it. Delphi API call is as direct as plain C. There is no Delphi wrapper function around.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez It's not as direct as your typical C or C++ compiler. As discussed ad nauseum. There is not Delphi wrapper function. But there is also no direct call. In other words the question as asked presents a false dichotomy. In fact the actuality is neither one nor the other, but a trampoline. Which part of my answer is not accurate? And please can you answer this: "Does a call to the Delphi Windows API function immediately call the Windows API function?"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `CALL DWORD PTR [__imp__CloseHandle@4]` is an *indirect call*, just as `CALL Windows.CloseHandle; JMP kernel32.CloseHandle`. And the 2nd may be faster, since it does not read any memory. The only direct call may be `CALL kernel32.CloseHandle` - which may be not faster than the other two.

Comment: @Arnaud It's a direct call with indirection on the address. Perf will, in all realistic cases be the same for all options. Nobody argues otherwise.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I argue about the fact that your answer is not correct. You answered: NO. And the correct answer is IMHO: YES. For instance, a JMP is by no way a call to any "thunk function", as you are writing. No stack frame. No parameter marshaling. No exception frame. It is just another way of doing indirection. Now you modified your answer too much to be consistent, and focusing on the question. Some comments here show that your answer was misleading and may lead into confusion (e.g. ctacke).

Comment: @Arnaud ctacke might have a point. I'm not sure. I edited my answer because I wanted to improve it. I think it is better now. Thank you to everyone for comments to help me improve it. I don't care about anything other than trying to get the facts straight.